# Dropdown in a submenu not visible despite Z-Index is set

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I really can't understand how to solve this issue. I am using Bootstrap 3, and adding the submenu functionality on top with an additional custom CSS.

The second level menu item is visible only in the submenu element visual part and not the part on the right:

[image]

[image]

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999999;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="menu-item ">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About The Tests
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Clearing Floats</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="menu-item ">
                <a href="#">Page with comments</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item ">
                <a href="#">Page with comments disabled</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">3rd level link more options</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">3rd level link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <form class="navbar-search navbar-form" method="get" action="">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="s">
        </form>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Subscribe to the RSS feed">
          <i class="icon-rss"> </i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>




  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>




</html>
```

Do you know how to make the menu visible? Where is my mistake? I set z-index higher in the element, display is block so I really don't know how to solve...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't neither make the snippet working...

Comment: It works fine in the snippet, so you'll have to show it working in context

Comment: Looks like you are facing some conflicts its working fine in the snippet
look into this screencast

https://www.screencast.com/t/tbEFE7hYuLH

Comment: Unfortunately I am inside a platform, but I noted that I can see the submenu only if I remove the class navbar-nav. If I leave only nav in the first UL tag then I see the submenus, but I loose the styles..

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right selectors for the hovering. This rule:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

should have this selector (just `.dropdown:hover` instead of `.dropdown-submenu:hover`) :

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
```

That change alone makes the dropdown work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGVQMm

But there might be other rules which you also should change

Comment: @joahhnes: I still see the bad behavior, but I can see the submenu only if I remove navbar-nav. Any idea about the reason??

Comment: That's impossible to tell - you don't have that `navbar-nav` class anywhere in the CSS code you posted, so I don't know what it does in your page.

Comment: It's in the first UL element under body, but it's quite challenging.. I thought it was a z-index issue, but this is not the case... very weird.

Comment: I saw it in the HTML code, but there is no CSS for it. As you saw, it works in my codepen, and that includes Bootstrap 3. So there must be something partucular in your code which causes this (and which isn't in the snippet you posted, and also not in Bootstrap). Is your original page public, can you provide a link?